# Создание ссылок на разные объекты Integer

Tags: java

Допустим имеем подобный код на Java:

```
Integer A = 1000;
Integer B = 1000;

System.out.println(A == B);
```

В данном случае имеем две ссылки на объект A и B, в данном случае ссылки различны, ведут к разным адресам в памяти. Однако, если поменять код на:

```
Integer A = 100;
Integer B = 100;

System.out.println(A == B);
```

То получаем разные ссылки, но уже ведущие к одному адресу памяти. Как же так получается? При этом, если использовать такой код:

```
Integer A = new Integer(1000);
Integer B = new Integer(1000);
 
System.out.println(A == B);
```

То создаются опять же ссылки на разные адреса памяти. Но IDE подсвечивает создание объекта — `new Integer()` не совсем корректным, так как, начиная с 9 версии конструктор является Deprecated. Соответсвенно сам вопрос: каким образом можно понять, как JVM выделит память для объекта, и можно ли где-то найти информацию по данной теме?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JVM хранит кеш маленьких значений `Integer` от -128 до 127. Если вы создаете `Integer` из маленького значения `int`, то возвращается кешированный объект. Сделано для экономии памяти и немного ускоряет программу. Ситуация напоминает интернирование строк, только тут вы не можете интернировать произвольный `Integer`.

Сравните `Integer A = 100;` (компилятор выполняет автобоксинг и задействует кеш) и `Integer A = new Integer(100);` (всегда возвращает новый объект).

Comment: Благодарю за ответ. А можно ли как-то создать, не используя new Integer() две разные ссылки на число, принадлежащее [-128; 127]? Или виртуальная машина всегда будет стремится использовать такую экономию памяти?

Comment: Я подозреваю, что конструкторы собираются убирать из языка именно потому что они **единственный** способ создавать маленькие целые которые не лежат в кеше.